# In ejabberd user left group when he goes offline

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

In group chat once user goes offline, he also goes out from group. How can I kept him in group so that he will receive chat notification as well when he comes online. I am using ejabberd and strophe js for web chat application.

Comment: have u found any solution for this???

Comment: I used a trick for this. I connected ejabberd with MySQL instead of mnesia. So whenever a user comes online, I programmatically add the user in his group and fetch all the conversation through an API call. Basically api fetch all the messages from MySQL database after the time user left the group. A lot of manual work and approach is not as good but for time being I used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-User Chat as defined in XEP-0045 is based on presence. Thus, that's the expected behaviour.

ejabberd also implements a work in progress extension written by the XSF: [XEP-0369: Mediated Information eXchange (MIX)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0369.html).

ejabberd master implements that specification already even if this is just a draft. At the moment, it is not finished and is just experimental. It cannot be used in production just yet.

Comment: Thank you Mickael for your comment !! But I want to build group chat like whats app, mean user will be added permanently and he will receive all the messages if he is offline. If you have worked around this can u help me how can we build this functionality using ejabberd ?

Comment: This feature does not exist in XMPP. There is a work in progress by the XSF: [XEP-0369: Mediated Information eXchange (MIX)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0369.html). ejabberd master implements that specification already even if this is just a draft. At the moment, it is not finished and is just experimental. It cannot be used in production just yet. You will likely have to wait for XSF progress and / or build custom extensions on top of it. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Mickaël Rémond, 

I wants to implement permanent group chat like whats app through ejabberd.
As you say above that "ejabberd also implements a work in progress extension written by the XSF: XEP-0369: Mediated Information eXchange (MIX)."

So Now can i use ejabbered for permanent group chat with XEP-0369 or still its in development phase? if it is still in development phase then could you please any other alternative solution for this?

Comment: I am planning to continue with openfire, MUC ... ping me on skype -
 er.sachin08